# Scraping table html python with selenium

Tags: html, python-3.x, xpath

I am trying to do Web Scraping to a page in python and selenium with xpath

```
def scrape(self):
data=[]
for tr in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table[@class="table expandable"]//tr'):
        #self.tds =tr.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
        self.tds =tr.find_elements_by_tag_name('th')
if self.tds: 
    data.append([td.text for td in self.tds])
```

And it gives me this error:

```
TypeError: scrape() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

**[See the structure of the page here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJkYy.png)**

Comment: You should ask your question in English. You can get help here: https://www.deepl.com/translator - Deberías hacer tu pregunta en inglés. Puede obtener ayuda aquí: https://www.deepl.com/translator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are non-English posts allowed here?

Anyways, I don't see any th tags in the tr tags shown in your code screenshot, I only see th tags. So maybe try:

```
self.tds =tr.find_elements_by_tag_name('th')
```

You don't need self:

```
def scrape():
    data=[]
    for tr in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table[@class="table expandable"]//tr'):
        #self.tds =tr.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
        tds =tr.find_elements_by_tag_name('th')
    if tds: 
        data.append([td.text for td in tds])
```

Comment: @SteevensonPierresaint I edited the answer. I don't see why you're using self?

Comment: it gives me this error: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'tds' referenced before assignment

Comment: Can we see the URL you're trying to scrape?

Comment: [link](https://tokbox.com/developer/tools/inspector/account/958621/project/6680791/session/)

Comment: I also have the image of the page's impedance, you can see the structure of what I would like to obtain "See the structure of the page here"

Comment: @SteevensonPierresaint Yes I saw that. In the <thead> element there is only the table headers. I'm assuming you need the table info in the <tbody>. I signed up with tokbox which page is this on?

Comment: Here id session [Link](https://tokbox.com/developer/tools/inspector/account/958621/project/6680791/session/2_MX42NjgwNzkxfn4xNTgyNzI2OTYzNzMzflo4cm5pUnJodGxKRzF1R2t5VWdqdlM0RX5Qfg)